# extend AppCompatActivity vs extend flutterActivity

Tags: flutter

In order https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation

We must use our code in MainActivity extends FlutterActivity

But in my working android app I have `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

I cant extend two classes like `extends AppCompatActivity,FlutterActivity`
What I should do? Can I use another java class for methodChannels?

**upd:2022 - FlutterActivity depricated**

Comment: Did you get any successful approach to this issue?

Comment: @Akif  I suppose flutterActivity include all features of AppCompatActivity, I just replace and use it AFAIK

Comment: I got a solution today. And I want to add here for the next visitors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I use another java class for methodChannels?

Yes, you can use another java class for methodChannels. You can write it anywhere in your application like this:

```
public class MyFlutterActivity extends FlutterActivity {
private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.io/battery";

@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(((methodCall, result) -> {
        if (methodCall.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {

            result.success("batteryLevel"); // It returns string "batteryLevel".

        } else {
            result.notImplemented();
        }
    }));
 }
}
```

Then you can start that Flutter engine with related class like this:

```
startActivity(
  new FlutterActivity.NewEngineIntentBuilder(MyFlutterActivity.class).build(getApplicationContext())
 );
```

Of course, you need to define that class in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <activity android:name=".MyFlutterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    />
```

Comment: Better use flutter cache engine for open flutter activity, insteed new FlutterActivity.NewEngineIntentBuilder, i suppose.