# Flutter: Extend FlutterActivity AND AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, flutter, appcompatactivity

I'm trying to create an android plugin for Flutter that depends on using an AppCompatActivity (as it has a method that takes the embedding appcompatactivity as a parameter).

However, since my main activity extends FlutterActivity, I cannot simultaneously extend AppCompatActivity. I tried implementing it instead, but failed because of some redundancies.

Is there any way to hack this?

Thanks

Comment: could you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

extend AppCompatActivity vs extend flutterActivity

you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529953/extend-appcompatactivity-vs-extend-flutteractivity)